# the best way to get "find" style output from "ls -fR"

Tags: linux, bash

My goal is to find the fastest way to list all available files in a directory (call it the master directory). The master directory contains about 5 million files, organized using subdirectories but it's unclear how subdirectories are arranged. After some research I realized that the fastest way to do so is using `ls -fR` (-f disables sorting)

The default output from `ls -fR` is something like this:

```
$ ls -fR dir1
dir1:
.  subdir1  ..

dir1/subdir1:
.  file1  ..
```

My desired output is the one produced by find (find takes twice as long though):

```
$ find dir1/ -type f
dir1/subdir1/file1
```

Although I can potentially parse the `ls -fR` result, I was wondering if there is a simple way to make `ls -fR` output in "find" style. I hope there is a very easy toggle and I'm just being blind to it

Comment: @JerryFan Give it a try to `ls -fR -p | grep -v /` as said in: https://askubuntu.com/a/811236/1025976

Comment: What do you need to do with the list of files? You should almost certainly be writing a program that iterates the file system, rather than trying to parse the output of `find` or `ls`.

Comment: Well I think that the real solution is to not *repeatedly* list all 5 million files.  Instead, do it once, and put the results into a database (or even a flat file) that you can query.  (5 million files in an disorganized structure sounds like what happens when someone doesn't teach a bunch of science PhD students and RAs about proper file management.  At least your 5 million files are not in HSM ...)

Comment: @JerryFan : You have the implicit restriction (`-type f`), that you are interested only in plain files, not directories. `ls` can't do this. Also, `ls` may get you in trouble if one of the files contains a newline character in its name. Perhaps you could also show the context, **how** you are going to use the list of file names being produced?

Comment: @StephenC This is exactly what `locate` does.

Comment: @Socowi - then you should mention that in your answer!

Comment: I already mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find takes twice as long

Interesting. Are you really sure though?

- `ls -fR` ignores hidden files and directories. Maybe `ls` just skips some of the work. Try `ls -fRA` too.
- If you run `find; ls -fR` the latter will have a *huge* advantage due to caching. Try swapping the order or clear the cache (`sync; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`) before each command.

> I hope there is a very easy toggle and I'm just being blind to it

Not that I would know. Posix [`ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/ls.html) certainly has no such thing. As far as I can tell from `man ls`, even GNU `ls` 8.32 has no such option.

You *could* adapt the output of `ls` to match that of `find` using

```
ls -fRpA | awk '/:$/ {sub(/:$/,"/"); p=$0; next} length() && !/\// {print p $0}'
```

Even though that would break on files/directories with linebreaks and files ending with a `:`. Also, you will slow down the script a bit. The longer the paths, the slower it gets, I'd assume. This could also explain partially why `find` is slower than `ls`. The former just prints a lot more text because it has to repeat the name of the top level directories over and over again.

**I strongly advise against using above script.** It is fragile and unreadable, likely just for the sake of premature optimization: Most certainly you want to do something with the printed list. That something will probably take more time than generating the list. Also, with different implementations running on different systems `find` may be faster than `ls` – you never know.

Also, don't parse the output of `ls`/`find`, instead use `find -exec` to do the actual task. If you really must, `find -print0` would be the safe option (can be replaced by `find -exec printf %s\\0 {} +` if not available on your system).

Depending on the task, `locate` might be a fast alternative to `find`. If not, try parallelizing `find` using something like `printf %s\\0 ./* | xargs -0 -I_ -P0 find _ -type f` or a tool like [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) that has built-in parallelization.